# How do I get positions of all visible text on screen?

Tags: winapi

In windows, say I have windows open with title bars, menus, buttons, text fields and a browser open with HTML displayed,

Is there a way to get the bounding boxes if all text on screen? I could probably access the positions of the open window gui elements, would I also be able to get the bounding box of html text on open webpages in the same way? How about pdf pages?

The reason i want to do this is to take a screenshot of the screen and compare it with the actual text to train a neural network to learn text recognition from screenshots.

Comment: What is "text"?  Are you including things prerendered into an image, and the application only blits the image?  Even for function calls calling the font system, it's going to be hard.  Finding images of prerendered text will be quite infeasible.

Comment: UI Automation is the closest you can get. It won't get you text displayed as an image, and it certainly won't get you any information for games rendered through a 3D API.

Comment: Nope im not bothered about text displayed as an image. Hmm maybe just all text that can be read by a screen reader for blind.